# Observer for Admin Order Grid

Tags: adminhtml, collection, event-observer

I would like to restrict order based on an Admin user. So for example the admin user would have an attribute that is assigned to a certain region (Group of Zipcodes). When the user logs in they could only see the orders for their region.

I am pretty clear on everything except the event to show the grid. I would like to accomplish this without overriding the core code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way - though I'm not terribly excited about it. Maybe someone has a better thought:

To avoid potential issues with your admin panel causing locks on your sales tables (think `sales_flat_order_address`) I would add appropriate columns for filter to the `sales_flat_order_grid` table that have your billing region. You don't have to display these with an `addColumn` - they'll only be used for applying a default filter to the collection.

Using the event `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before`:

```
class Yc_Ym_Model_Observer
{

    public function gridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
       $allowedRegionId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getAllowedRegionId();
       $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();
       $collection->addFieldToFilter('billing_region',array('eq'=>$allowedRegionId));

    }

}
```

This allows you to filter the collection by default. You could skip this entire block conditionally (for instance, super admins who can view all regions) by doing a `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed()` which, in essence, does an ACL check to skip this filter application. You would be responsible for setting this ACL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend observing for loading of Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection and on before load event add your filters. `sales_order_collection_load_before` should be the event to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this event `admin_session_user_login_success`

For further usefulness refer the following urls.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/